# Copy files with GNU make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to copy several files. Doing a makefile:

```
FILES=foo.txt d1/bar.dat d2/baz.txt
TARGETDIR=/app

targets=$(addprefix $(TARGETDIR)/,$(FILES))

all: $(targets)

$(targets): $(FILES)
        cp $(subst $(TARGETDIR)/,,$@) $@
```

Files copied correctly, but if I do `touch foo.txt`, all three files are copied.

I know that "the correct way" is to define three rules like:

```
$(TARGETDIR)/foo.txt: foo.txt
    cp $^ $@
$(TARGETDIR)/d1/bar.dat: d1/bar.dat
    cp $^ $@
$(TARGETDIR)/d2/baz.txt: d2/baz.txt
    cp $^ $@
```

But in this case I have to write names of the files twice, once for these rules and once for `all` rule.

Is there a way to 'multiply' the rule for each name in the prerequisite?
Something like

```
$(TARGETDIR)/%: $(FILES)
   cp $< $@
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the target name using the text manipulation functions, if you use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(targets): $$(patsubst $(TARGETDIR)/%, %, $$@)
    echo cp $< $@
```

This is not the only way, but it's probably the simplest.